# Selectively enable / disable endpoints on a RestAPI project

Tags: asp.net-core

I've got an application that has some endpoints that should be incrementally enabled in production...at the current moment, I've used a `#if !PROD /#endif` directive that disables the ones that should not be shown... but I was wondering, is there a better way to enable them in swagger-ui/ for usage?

I've thought of using a JSON file with the list of the endpoints and their status and loading them at startup, but I don't know how to hide them from Swagger and how to return a 404 if invoked.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the scenario in order to visualize accordingly. Not sure, how the endpoint is showing in swagger UI.